# Javascript what is "...array"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I can't seem this find this anywhere on the net. What does it mean when we prefix an array with "..."? for example when we are using Math.min on this array to get the shortest string we use "...".

```
var arr = ['cats', 'giants', 'daughters', 'ice'];
var min = Math.min(...arr.map(({ length }) => length));
console.log(min);
```

i'm really sorry if this is a duplicate but I can't find anywhere what this means.

Comment: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator

Comment: It really depends on the context. `...` means different things in different contexts, just like `,`. In your case it’s a *spread argument*.